# Php files charset encoding - fgetcsv?

Tags: php, csv, utf-8, character-encoding, prestashop

This is the error i get when i try to import products directly to the Prestashops database using external script

> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Spol" [1]=> string(1) "?" }
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO
> ed_feature_product (id_feature, id_product, id_feature_value)
> VALUES (1, 313, )
> ```
>
> thrown in
>   ...../Db.php on line 765

So I basically have to check if in a csv file there is a product with an id equal to the one on in database. If there isn't one i have to add it directly to a database. I've done everything right and when there is no croatian signs everything works like a charm. The problem is when the script encounters croatian signs (č,ć,ž,š,đ,Č,Ć,Ž,Š,Đ). It's like it doesn't recognize them.

I.e the firs line of the quote is the thing i var_dumped to the screen. Where there is a question mark sign it should've outputted the "Ž" sign.

It clearly isn't recognized as Ž since it throws errors since i'm using that sing to select all the *id_feature_value* where *value = Ž* (in this example). Since i'm including prestashops config.inc.php file into this script charset is set to utf-8 as is the header.

Maybe it's not done properly so where can I check it? 
If it is what is causing this problem and how can i solve it

**P.S.** I think the problem is that i'm using fgetcsv to read the whole csv file and it doesn't recognize it's encoding therefore outputting weird signs instead of outputting propper croatian signs. What could be solution for this problem?

**P.P.S** On request import function:

```
function CSVToArray() {
    $arr = [];
    if (($fp = fopen('csv/products.csv', 'r')) !== FALSE) {
        $i = 0;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($fp, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
            $arr[$i]['reference'] = $data[0];
            $arr[$i]['naziv'] = utf8_decode($data[1]);
            $arr[$i]['price'] = $data[2];

            if (empty($data[3])) {
                $arr[$i]['quantity'] = 0;
            } else {
                $arr[$i]['quantity'] = $data[3];
            }

            $arr[$i]['kat_naziv'] = array_map('trim', explode(',', utf8_decode($data[4])));
            $arr[$i]['slika'] = $data[5];
            $arr[$i]['spol'] = utf8_decode($data[6]);
            $i++;
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your import script? Or just the part where you read and parse the file.

Comment: i just now see that i've used utf8_decode for some reason and maybe that is where the problem lies.

Comment: 1) I see you have both `utf8_decode()` and non-latin characters. You simply cannot do that. 2) If data can cause a SQL syntax error, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've really messed this one up using `utf8_decode()` where it wasn't needed and that caused all my headaches.